# Android App for C Programming

Tags: android, c, programming, google-apps

I plan on using my android tablet and smartphone for my college course in C programming. The PC software is given by the school, however I would like to use my android devices as well for practice.  What is the best android app(s) for C Programming?

Comment: terminal emulator and a shell account on some reachable *nix machine with a proper C compiler and libraries and such installed.

Comment: Do you need a debugger, or just compiler & linker?

Answer (score 1):

Here are few in the list:

- [Decoder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paprbit.dcoder&hl=en-GB)
- [Cppdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.antonsmirnov.android.cppdroid&hl=en-GB)
- [C4droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc&hl=en-GB) & [GCC Plugin for c4droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.gcc4droid&hl=en-GB)
- [Programming Hub](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freeit.java&hl=en-GB), for other languages also